# About Power BI desktop connect to a report server remotely

Tags: remote-access, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am facing a problem where I need to use Power BI desktop to connect to a power bi report server which in a remote server. I got an "unexpected error encountered". I test to connect the report server with a browser, it succeeded by entering the remote authentication. Any solution to workaround. The remote server firewall has been turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI desktop(Remote server) take current local user login credential as the remote login information. Need to assign the user at remote server to connect...